# How to save each element of a list to an independent new file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I have a function that [Pos-tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) a number of documents and prints each pos-tagged document in a list as follows:

```
    [u'I\tPP\tI', u'am\tVBP\tbe', u'an\tDT\tan', u'amateur\tJJ\tamateur']
....

    [u'good\tJJ\tgood', u'camera\tNN\tcamera', u'for\tIN\tfor', u'a\tDT\ta', u'good\tJJ\tgood']
```

How can I save or write each list as a new .txt document in a new directory?, for example:

```
new_directory
    ---->list1.txt
    ....
    ---->listn.txt
```

Now, if we look inside each new file it would look like this:

```
good JJ good
camera NN camera
for IN for
a DT a
good JJ good
```

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: can you give an example? What do you want list1.txt to look like? Do you want each list as a document or each item in each list as a document?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Racialz, each list as a document.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show exactly how you want list1.txt to look. Do you want each list item separated by newlines or what?

Comment: I updated the question with more details, thanks for the feedback @Racialz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one way you can iterate over your lists (I assumed they're in a nested list here) and then open a file and write the contents of that list to the file.

You could hardcode the path with the appropriate seperators, but I just used os.path.join here as it's typically good to use this. How you're specifying the new directory wasn't mentioned. You could take this in from sys.argv, a file dialog, input, or any other numerous options.

```
import os

nested_list=[
    [u'I\tPP\tI', u'am\tVBP\tbe', u'an\tDT\tan', u'amateur\tJJ\tamateur'],
    [u'good\tJJ\tgood', u'camera\tNN\tcamera', u'for\tIN\tfor', u'a\tDT\ta', u'good\tJJ\tgood']
]

for i, a_list in enumerate(nested_list):
    #new_dir_path is path to dir you want.
    path = os.path.join(new_dir_path, "list%d.txt" % i) #or "list{}.txt".format(i)
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        for item in a_list:
            f.write(item+"\n") #\n if you want each item on a new line
```

Comment: with open("list{}.txt".format(i), "w") as f: I'm curious why you don't do this, Is there any reason?

Comment: Not really just personal preference you can use either. I find `.format(..)` to be more drawn out for simple cases like this. It's just shorter to use `%`. You could even format `.write(..)` if you really wanted to

Comment: @Thanks for the help guys, for a very large number of documents do you think this is efficent?.